# Data fetching not happening when I use two parameters in React Router Dom and navigate directly on the page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, single-page-application, url-routing

I faced a really strange and complex problem with React Router. I am trying to implement a single page application with a varying number of pages that depends on the number of products in the json file.
In my app I have the main page that always consist only of one pages thus it has only one paramater which is called :section. The bug I'm stuck with happens only when I use the second parameter :page_number, all other pages have this parameter.

This is my main component that contains various pages and depends on the router params

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import GoodsList from './GoodsList';
import Pages from './Pages';

function Sections() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path='' element={<>
                <div className="pageContent" data-main="true">
                    <p>Novelties</p>
                    <GoodsList goods="novelties" />
                    <p>Hot</p>
                    <GoodsList goods="hot" />
                </div>
            </>} />
            <Route path='/:section/:page_number' element={<>
                <div className='pageContent'>
                    <GoodsList />
                    <Pages />
                </div>
            </>} />
        </Routes>
    )
```

This component I use for navigation on the page

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Menu() {
    return (
        <nav className='menu'>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="">Main</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="figures/1">Figures</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="dakimakuras/1">Figures</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="manga/1">Manga</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="other/1">Other merch</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

And finaly this component displays the list of products

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchProducts } from '../redux/fetchDataReducer';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function GoodsList(props) {
    const params = useParams();
    const goods = returnGoods();
    function returnGoods() {
        if (document.location.pathname == "/") {
            return props.goods
        }
        return params.section
    }
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchProducts());
    }, [])
    
    const products = useSelector(state => state.fetchDataReducer.products);
    
    return (
        <div className="list">
            {products && products[goods].map((good, i) => (
                <div className="productCard" key={i}>
                    <div className="productPicture">
                        <img src={good.pic} alt="ERROR" />
                    </div>
                    <p className="productName">{good.name}</p>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

The thing is when I click on the main page in the nav bar or move to it directly by typing the path in the address bar it always works fine. Then if I click on any section in the nav bar everything works fine either, BUT if I will try to refresh the page or move to any of the pages except the main by directly typing its address in the bar the GoodsList component won't load the products list. The fetching of data won't happen somehow, but the component itself and all the parameters from the address bar will be loaded fine. BUT if I will move to the main page again and then to any other section by using the nav Link it will be loaded fine again and the problem won't appear till I refresh the page.

So, the problem appears only if I have the :page_number parameter and affects only the data I recieve from json file through Redux. If I delete this second parameter the bug won't happen. It happens when I move to any section with this parameter directly or refresh the page, if I use navigation links on my menu bar it works fine but ONLY if I visited the main page before that.

UPD. Adding the pages component

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function Pages() {
    const params = useParams();
    const products = useSelector(state => state.fetchDataReducer.products);
    const currentProduct = products ? products[params.section] : [];
    const pageLinks = [];

    let numberOfPages = () => {
        if ((currentProduct.length / 8) % 1 == 0) {
            return currentProduct.length / 8
        }
        else return Math.floor((currentProduct.length / 8) + 1)
    }

    for (let x = 1; x < (numberOfPages() + 1); x++) {
        pageLinks.push(<Link to={`/${params.section}/${x}`} className="pageLink" key={x}>{x}</Link>);
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="pageList">
            {pageLinks}
        </div>
    )
}
```

UPD. Codesandbox example
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/TheDanieLSh/React-Sites/draft/modest-hopper?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cli1ipbjf00iu356lorpxfmbk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cli1ipbjf00iu356lorpxfmbk%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cli1ipbje00it356lhcqi48gt%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.gitignore%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cli1ipbjf00iu356lorpxfmbk%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cli1ipbje00it356lhcqi48gt%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D

Comment: Where is the `page_number` route path param referenced? It doesn't appear to be used anywhere. It's a little unclear what the issue is from your description. Is there more code to include in the [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese It is used in the Pages component and for now it just generates the list of links to other pages, this component isn't completed yet. But even if I delete the Pages component nothing changes

Comment: I don't see where any `page_number` path parameter is referenced or used. I ***do*** see where `Pages` is rendering `Link` components to the ***literal*** path string `"/:page_number"`, but nothing else. Are you really wanting to link to sub-routes of the current `"/:section"` route?

Comment: @DrewReese There was a mistake in the 'link to' path, I fixed it. I didn't yet implemented the usage of the :page_number parameter because I faced the bug. The GoodsList component will take this parameter and return the required part of the products array depending on the page number

Comment: I was going to say that *that* error usually indicates a missing/undefined `to` prop on the `Link` component, but the code snippets you shared the links were passed that prop. So is there still some issue?

Comment: @DrewReese Yeah, the issue still here unfortunately

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What data is the code trying to fetch, and where?

Comment: @DrewReese It is a simple json file in the public folder. As I said, the problem appears only when the second parameter added and everything works fine if I load the main page (that doesn't contain the second parameter in the path) first and then move to other sections via Links, but if I refresh the page on any section the problem appears

Comment: I still don't understand what you are saying is a problem. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue, and include the reproduction steps necessary to cause it?

Comment: @DrewReese The products array in the GoodsList component doesn't receive the data, everything else works fine

Comment: This `const products = useSelector(state => state.fetchDataReducer.products);`? The expected redux state `products` value isn't selected? What data are you expecting it to receive, and what does that mean?

Comment: @DrewReese It is a json file, containing strings. This data allows to generate the list of products, the goods variable defines the needed array inside json, thus the expected type of product appears in the list

Comment: It seems that `goods` will either be the `props.goods` value or whatever the `section` path param value is. The `page_number` path param still doesn't appear to be relevant here. Is there more relevant code that you haven't shared? What happens when you reload the page? Any errors? Anything that provides better details what any issue might be? See if you can create a sandbox that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @DrewReese I've made the sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetchProducts` action is using a ***relative*** resource path for the `products.json` file it's fetching/loading from the `"/public"` directory.

```js
fetch("products.json")
```

This works fine and as expected when the app is currently sitting on the root `"/"` route rendering the `GoodsList` component when is dispatches `fetchProducts`. The `products.json` resource is requested ***relative*** to the current URL path, e.g. `"/products.json"` and the data is loaded into the Redux store without issue.

Upon navigating to the sub-route, e.g. `"/:section/:page_number"`, the `products.json` file is now requested ***relative*** to *that* path, e.g. `"/figures/1/products"` which doesn't exist in the public directory. When the user is on a sub-route and reloads the page, the fetch just fails. This is fine so long as the user at least (*eventually*) lands on the main `"/"` page so when the request is made it actually succeeds.

To resolve you can simply specify an ***absolute*** resource path to `"/products.json"`.

```js
fetch("/products.json")
```

```js
export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  "dataFetch/fetchProducts",
  async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/products.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }
);
```

[image: Edit data-fetching-not-happening-when-i-use-two-parameters-in-react-router-dom-and-na]